# How to hold other process while one is processing in Javascript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript

I have a function which does init steps. However, when I check my result, it seems like other processes after init function already finished. How can I hold other processes?

Comment: I'm in the middle of a project so it's kind of complicate to show as an example. Thanks anyway!

Comment: JavaScript is single-threaded. It is very unlikely that the state changes during a function call, which is not initiated by that function call.

You have to let uw know what changes during your init-function.

Comment: You really should spend a moment boiling your code down to a small example that demonstrates the problem. This skill is an essential part of effective bugfixing and will also help you get more informed answers here on SO.

Comment: Thanks spender! I'll keep in mind and try :)

Answer (score 0):

Hard to give a sure answer without seeing any code. But generally, the only way you can tell if something is completed is by having a flag setting in your script, which is set at completion of your init function. You can use **setTimeout** in your init function to check for this flag, and fire off the next function when the flag has been set.

Again, hard to say without seeing the code, but maybe that helps.